# XML character entity reference

Tags: java, xml

I'm parsing some data from an XML document then write it back to another XML document. I face a problem where the data in the original one is written in CDATA section.

This is an example of the input :

```
<actions><![CDATA[<div>
check that&#39;s is sent </div>
```

I simply replaced div , p etc. with `substring` function, but my output was

```
<logical>check that &amp;#39; is sent </logical>
```

I want the content of the output to appear to be the same as the input:

```
<logical>check that's is sent </logical>
```

I tried using substring as well, like this:

```
string= string.replaceAll("&#\\d+;", " 39");
```

but the problem now is that this number is variable so I need to replace the current regex with the number inside the `&#numl;`

Also the string may include many numbers so I couldn't just search for a number inside it , something like this:

```
check that&#39;s is sent and&#42;s is received
```

Comment: Parsing how? Why not use the existing XML parsers in java like DOM or SAX?

Comment: I changed the title to reference XML entities to allow people to recognize the question. Fixed up punctuation and layout.

Comment: @Progman I stated above that the text is written in Cdata section , I parse it using DOM but I still get a literal XML text  containing tags and escape characters , I'm not sure why he stored his text in cdata section , but I'm a front end in this case and I have to handle it .

Comment: there is actually another solution to the whole problem which is taking each string and put it as it is in another XML document then parse it once more , but this gave me too many errors to handle because tags like div for example were comprehended as children . thanks anyway .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this function to find all occurrences of the numeric character reference and return it with just the number

```
public static String decode(String str) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int i1=0;
    int i2=0;

    while(i2<str.length()) {
       i1 = str.indexOf("&#",i2);
       if (i1 == -1 ) {
            sb.append(str.substring(i2));
            break ;
       }
       sb.append(str.substring(i2, i1));
       i2 = str.indexOf(";", i1);
       if (i2 == -1 ) {
            sb.append(str.substring(i1));
            break ;
       }

       String appnd = str.substring(i1+2, i2);




             sb.append(" "+appnd);

        i2++ ;
    }
    return sb.toString();}
```